# Get field that contains search query

Tags: templating, field, search

After a standard search with something like:

```
{% set results = craft.entries.search( query ) %}
{% for result in results %}
    <ul>
        <li>{{ result.link }}</li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to find out which field the query was found in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This currently isn't possible natively in Craft, but if you think it should be,  you can create a [feature request](http://feedback.craftcms.com/)!

Comment: I couldn't find an existing feature request, so... http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/14212509-search-results-included-the-field-that-matched-the

Comment: Here's a plugin to add the matched field and matched value to the results.
https://github.com/composedcreative/craft-expandedsearch